# SQL UPDATE IF password is correct

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code :

```
$userpass = $row->userpass;
$gesamtpass = $pass.$chili;
$pwdata = mysql_query("SELECT MD5('".$gesamtpass."') AS newpass");
$pwk = mysql_fetch_object($pwdata);
$pwkey = $pwk->newpass;

$_POST["email"] = $email;
$_POST["fbuid"] = $fbuid;

if ($userpass == $pwkey){
  $result_update = mysql_query("UPDATE member SET (fbuid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fbuid"])."')  WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'") or die("not possible");}
```

I don´t get this code work updating my data.

Comment: Why are you doing all of that messing around with `SELECT MD5()...` instead of just using the PHP [`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) function? And why are you assigning values to `$_POST`? This holds user input, and should be treated as read only.

Comment: Is your if condition satisfying..!

Comment: No need to call `MD5()` in a `mysql_query()`. Just use PHP's own native `md5()` http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: And how exactly does it fail to work, if I might ask? (BTW, very creative way to avoid PHP's [md5()](http://php.net/md5) function-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does what you want to do in a tidier way. It also outputs some useful error messages when things go wrong. Obviously, you should not output these directly to the user in production, but it will help you debug the problem while developing.

```
// Is this already an MD5 hash?
$userpass = $row->userpass;
// MUCH simpler way to do MD5
$pwkey = md5($pass.$chili);

if ($userpass == $pwkey) { // Compare the passwords
  // If they match, do the query
  $query = "UPDATE member
            SET fbuid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($fbuid)."'
            WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'";
  mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Query Error: ".mysql_error());
} else {
  // They don't match, lets look at the data and find out why
  die("They don't match! $userpass != $pwkey");
}
```

Comment: I changed the code like U told me and included it to my site. The check for the following code works: if ($userpass==$pwkey){echo "match";} else {echo "mo match";}; the Problem is that there are no data for fbuid filled in mysql. I can echo all data in this page but the are not stored. field: fbuid, type:VARCHAR, length:35, utf8_general_ci, NULL: not null

Comment: what do you get if you `echo $fbuid;` before the query?

Comment: JUHU, I solved the problem: $email was not accepted, i changed variable to $mem_id and it functions at once!!!!!!!! So I think the problem is the @ inside but I´m not sure :) BUT now it works

Answer (score 0):

Whats the error message?

1) You can generate MD5 hashes in php directly [(md5 In php)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.md5.php) which should reach a better performance.

2) Have you checked (by a simple echo ) if $userpass == $pwkey is true?

3) try to remove the

> or die("not possible");

part, to get a sql error (if there is one)

4) It seems to me, that you did not understand how to use $_POST[] Variables, bcause you assign them values!?!?!?!

Answer (score -1):

```
$userpass = $row->userpass;
$gesamtpass = $pass.$chili;
$pwdata = mysql_query("SELECT MD5('".$gesamtpass."') AS newpass");
$pwk = mysql_fetch_object($pwdata);
$pwkey = $pwk->newpass;

$_POST["email"] = $email;
$_POST["fbuid"] = $fbuid;

if ($userpass == $pwkey)
{
  $result_update = mysql_query("UPDATE member SET fbuid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fbuid"])."'  WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'") or die("not possible");
 }
```

without using braces() for the fields to update

Comment: Just removed the braces for the query next to SET (fbuid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fbuid"]) to SET fbuid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fbuid"]